# How to set a tuple property in C#? Setting a tuple causes stackoverflow error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties, set, tuples

This is my first time working with tuples.

```
public (float minX, float maxX, float minY, float maxY) BoundsTuple
{
    private get => BoundsTuple;
    set 
    { 
        BoundsTuple = value;
    }

}
```

```
// BoundsTuple = value; causes stackoverflow error
```

This is my Unity console error:

> StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
> Clump.set_BoundsTuple (System.ValueTuple`4[T1,T2,T3,T4] value) (at Assets/Scripts/EverythingClouds/Clump.cs:17)

How can I fix this?

Not to get a stackoverflow while setting the tuple property

Comment: You’re setting the value of your property, a cyclic operation. Try `public (float minX, float maxX, float minY, float maxY) BoundsTuple { get; set; }` instead.

Comment: `_boundsTuple = value;
public (float minX, float maxX, float minY, float maxY) BoundsTuple
{
    private get => _boundsTuple;
    set 
    { 
         _boundsTuple = value;
    }
}` I think I wanted to write something like this. Is that correct? Otherwise, it is a cyclic operation as in the article above.

Comment: Thank you, I have been using autoproperties without customizing for such a while that I forgot to use a field. I do need to customize it later on, so I created a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about a tuple this is about properties in general.

Both the `get` and `set` of your property `BoundsTuple` refer to the very same `BoundsTuple` property again.

You will either convert this to an auto-property

```
public (float minX, float maxX, float minY, float maxY) BoundsTuple { get; set; }
```

or introduce a backing field

```
private (float minX, float maxX, float minY, float maxY) _boundsTuple;
public (float minX, float maxX, float minY, float maxY) BoundsTuple
{
    get => _boundsTuple;
    set => _boundsTuple= value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Milan's answer:

> You’re setting the value of your property, a cyclic operation. Try
> public (float minX, float maxX, float minY, float maxY) BoundsTuple {
> get; set; } instead.